# Learning R-Code Review on Subsetting Data

Tags: r

Instructions:*

- Create an object called `response` that contains the name of the variable that will be considered the response variable.
- Create a vector called `predictors` that contains the names of the variables that will be used as predictors.

*Assignment Code:*

```
# Create response object
response = 'price'

# Create predictors object
predictors = c("carat","cut","clarity","color","depth")
```

*Feedback:*
Now that you've identified what variables are of interest, you can subset the data to only include those columns.

**Subsetting the Data**

*Context:*
There are various ways to subset a data frame to only include specific columns. Here, you can use the objects `response` and `predictors` to indicate the names of the columns to keep. The function `select()`, from the `{dplyr}` package, is a good way to accomplish this task. It requires two arguments:

- the name of the data frame being used
- the column names to be included in the subset, or the objects that contain that information (`response` and `predictors`), separated by a comma

*Instructions:*

- Use `select()` to create a subset of `myData`  that contains only the columns of interest, and store this subset in an object called `myData_subset`.

*Assignment Code:*

```
# Subset the data
myData_subset %>% select(response,predictors)
```

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong on subsetting? Is it that my objects were created incorrectly? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: the assignment is lacking `myData` and Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous -> we could use `all_of(..)`

```
response = 'price'

predictors = c("carat","cut","clarity","color","depth")


myData_subset <- myData %>% 
  select(response,all_of(predictors))
```

Comment: My guess: it's the `diamonds` dataset included in `ggplot2` (or some other `tidyverse` package).

Comment: HI Martin Gal, it is .  I am trying to familiarize myself around R with it.

Comment: Hi TarJae! Ran it and got the following: Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
ℹ Use `all_of(response)` instead of `response` to silence this message.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
This message is displayed once per session.

Comment: This is a note message and OK.